# TypeError: t is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, jwt

I'm getting this "TypeError: t is not a function" error in loginCheck and I don't understand why. The error comes from the lines where I call the callback function fn.

```
loginCheck(jwt, fn){
    if(jwt !== null){
        req("jwt="+encodeURIComponent(jwt), "verifyJWT.php", (response)=>{
            fn(response);
        });
    }
    else{
        fn("Fail");
    }
}
```

I'm using this exact same syntax in in my login -function with no problems:

```
login(user, pass, fn){
    var creds = "t="+user+"&s="+pass;
    req(creds, "login.php", (response)=>{
        if(response && response.length > 0){
            fn(response);
        }
        else{
            fn(response);
        }
    });
},
```

The callbacks are in my react components and looks like this:

```
componentWillMount(){
    funcs.loginCheck(localStorage.getItem("jwt"), (response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

---

```
onClick(){
    funcs.login(this.state.username, this.state.password, (response)=>{
        if(response != 0 && response !== false){
            // on successful login, response should be a json web token
            localStorage.setItem("jwt", response);
            this.props.history.push("/");
        }
        else{
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the `req` function?

Comment: the req -function is just an xmlhttprequest and it works. I get the answer but calling the fn -callback throws an error (only in loginCheck -function)

Comment: You say it works, yet there is a problem in your code somewhere that you have been unable to identify. Please present a [MCVE].

Comment: The problem seems to be the componentWillMount -hook. If I change it to componentDidMount the callbacks aren't undefined anymore.

Comment: can you add your req function to the answer so that we can understand what it does? I was not able to reproduce the error without it.